# Accord du participe passé avec "être" comme auxiliaire et l'objet placé après le participe

Tags: accord, participe-passé, auxiliaires

Je connais la plupart des règles concernant l'accord du participe passé, mais ici j'ai un souci :

> Sais-tu où est lancée la fonction?

Est-ce:

- correct, car *fonction* est féminin et on utilise *être* comme verbe auxiliaire?
- faux, car, dans la phrase, la partie au féminin est placée après le participe?

Merci

Comment: Dans la phrase que tu donnes *la fonction* est **sujet** de *est lancée* (qu'est-ce qui est lancée ? → la fonction) . Et l'accord avec être se fait avec le sujet. Donc « la fonction est lancé**e** », c'est correct.  C'est avec les verbes conjugués avec *avoir* que l'accord se fait éventuellement avec le COD.

Comment: Merci: je m'étais trompé en mélangeant l'objet du verbe `lancer` et le sujet du verbe `être`: l'aspect syntactique d'être un sujet est plus important que l'aspect significatif d'être objet.

Comment: Pas toujours simple ces histoires d'accord ! Mais en fin de compte tu avais bien fait l'accord !

Comment: @Lambie C'est l'auxiliaire *être*. Pourquoi poser cette question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imaginons la phrase :

> Trucmuche lance la fonction « Hey Trucmuche » pour rivaliser avec Machinchose.

On a :
Sujet : Trucmuche (**qui** lance quelque chose ? → Trucmuche)
COD : la fonction (Trucmuche lance **quoi** ? → la fonction)

Maintenant je change cette phrase active en phrase passive :

> La fonction « Hey Trucmuche » est lancée (par Trucmuche).

Le verbe c'est *est lancée* (et non plus *lance*) et le sujet de *est lancée* c'est « la fonction ». (Qu'est-ce qui est lancée ? → la fonction).  L'accord avec le verbe *être* se fait avec le sujet de *être*.